# Spring Security или Сервлетные фильтры

Tags: java, spring, servlet, filter, spring-security

Реализовывал авторизацию и аутентификацию через сервлетные фильтры, а потом решил попробовать Spring Security, второй вариант выглядит более громоздким, но я понимаю, что этот фраемворк не просто так же написали :) Подскажите пожалуйста, какие плюсы и минусы у Spring Security по отношению к сервлетным фильтрам (я понимаю, что он на них и построен, но что именно там реализовано, что может пригодится). Безопасность должна быть на очень высоком уровне, возможно, двухфакторная. Интересует аргументы "за" и "против".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почитайте зачем люди вообще придумали фреймворки. Если все что вас интересует - авторизация пользователя, нет никакой разницы напишете вы реализацию самостоятельно или возьмете фреймворк. Задача простая, ошибиться трудно. Но с ростом вашего приложения вам могут потребоваться дополнительные опции:

- ограничение прав пользователей к определенным URL;
- basic authentication для REST сервиса;
- дополнительный realm;
- JSP / Thymeleaf тэги;
- OpenID

...

Фреймворк предоcтавляет вам это "из коробки". Spring Security, например, интегрируется с другими библиотеками (что дополнительно упрощает вам задачу), позволяет расширять себя дополнительными возможностями, переопределять стандартное поведение.

Вы можете написать требуемый функционал самостоятельно (по сути написать свой фреймворк). Да взять тот же Spring Security и посмотреть как у них реализовано. И упереться в тот факт, что:

- ваш код содержит ошибки - мы все ошибаемся, его надо постоянно поддерживать, а у вас уже нет на это времени - вы взялись за другой проект;
- вы уже не помните, когда и зачем написали какой-то кусок кода, он выглядит страшно и не пойми как работает;
- у вас что-то перестает работать, вы идете на форум, но никто больше не может разобрать костыль, который соорудили;

Если ваш проект учебный - развлекайтесь на здоровье. Если вы пишете в продакшн, то должны оценивать риски: проблемы роста вашего приложения, простоту последующий поддержки, времени которое у вас это займет, взаимодействия с командой. И выбирать соотвествующий инструмент.

Основные аргументы за фреймворк - это стандартизация и интеграция.

> Безопасность должна быть на очень высоком уровне

Безопасность приложения - это весь ваш код, а не один его кусок, относящийся к авторизации. Spring Security не спасет от SQL Injection, если вы не умеете пользоваться JDBC. Он не решает проблемы все безопасности одним фактом своего присутствия в проекте.

P.S. Посмотрите также в сторону [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/), я пока не видел Spring Security в свзяке с сервлетами. Обычно берут весь Spring.

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ спасибо за ваш ответ, я и не собирался использовать его в связке с сервлетами. Если всё-таки будет решено юзать Security, то будет MVC.